# Is it valid practice to have two start up projects in .Net Core, with one of them being identity server?

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, identity

I have a .net core microservice which has an Angular front end(not in the .net solution). I have just added a .net core identity project to the solution. The main project(business logic etc) will start first and then the identity project will fire up after. I presume this will not be an issue as all endpoints of the main project will need tokens from the identity project. Just not sure if this is valid practice or not?

.net solution - microservice
.project a - business logic, controllers, data layer
.project b - identity

Comment: Visual Studio lets you specify multiple startup projects for reasons such as this. Shouldn't the identity server start first so it can take requests though?

Comment: You are right. I have switched the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, having a shortcut on taskbar for bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NameOfYourIdentityS.exe file, start it and leave it open, much easier than having multiple startup projects, assuming that IdentityS is not changing very often and even if it does, you can quickly restart it this way. Also, as suggested by @Mike Cheel, this should run first.

Comment: Thanks that's a useful tip.